# CakePHP 3.4.3 Logging does not work in plugin

Tags: plugins, authentication, finder, cakephp-3.x

I have a login problem. New user registration works, password is encrypted, but I can not login. My login action is in the UsersAcces plugin and I think this is a problem. What's wrong?

Config Auth in src/AppController:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'plugin' => 'UsersAcces'
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'plugin' => 'UsersAcces',
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'plugin' => 'UsersAcces'
        ],
        'authError' => 'Brak dostępu!',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'username','password'=>'password'],
                'userModel'=>'UsersAcces.Users',
                'relatedModel' => ['UsersAcces.Roles', 'UsersAcces.Addresses', 'UsersAcces.Emails', 'UsersAcces.Permissions', 'UsersAcces.Telephones'],//'UsersAcces.Roles',
                'finder' => 'auth'
            ]
        ],
        'storage' => 'Session',
        'autoRedirect' => false
    ]);
```

Action login i plugins/UsersAcces/src/Controller/Users:

```
public function login(){
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout("login");


    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }else{
            $this->Flash->error(__('Niewłaściwy login lub hasło. Spróbuj ponownie.'));
        }
    }
    //$user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    $this->set(compact("user"));

}
```

Function findAuth in plugins/UsersAcces/src/Model/Table/UsersTable:

```
public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{   
    $query
        ->select()
        ->where(['Users._delete' => 0]);
    return $query;
}
```

Function setPassword in plugins/UsersAcces/src/Model/Entity/User:

```
protected function _setPassword($password)
{
    if (strlen($password) > 0) {
      return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! I did not add a line to file "plugins/UsersAcces/src/Controller/Users":

```
$this->Auth->setUser($user);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the password Hasher under the 'Form' key in your Auth component initialization params, like:

`'authenticate' => array(
    'Form' => array(
        'passwordHasher' => 'Default'
    )
),`